# I want to get the data sorted by publish date from RSS in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rss, fetch

I want to get the data sorted by publish date from RSS in react native

I used this code :

```
fetch('url here')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    this.setState({
      description : rss.items,
      isLoading : true
    });
    rss.items.map((value, index) => {
      this.setState({
        dateStack : this.state.description[index].published
      });
    });
  });
```

In here, dateStack is the array of data sorted date
But it doesn't get the sorted data, only get the one data...
Who can help me?
Please let me know how to do this~

Comment: `setState` is async so you can't rely on `this.state` in your map method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is the first `setState` asynchronous and unreliable to reference immediately with `this.state.description`, the reason why `dateStack` only has a single data point is because you're overwriting it at every iteration in the map. If you want `dateStack` to be just an array of the `published` property of every element in `rss.items`, you can just use `map`:

```
.then((rss) => {
    this.setState({
        description: rss.items,
        isLoading: true,
        dateStack: rss.items.map(item => item.published)
    });
})
```

Comment: but it has no result.

Comment: are you sure each `rss.items` element even has a `published` property? we can't see the data structure you're dealing with and can only make assumptions  from what you've provided

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, map is a good approach to get array of data but sometimes it is hard to understand instead of using it, use **for loop** to map your data. here is the simple way to do this.

```
fetch('url here')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
    .then((rss) => {

        var l_Data = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < rss.length; index++)
        {
            l_Data[index] = rss[index];
        }
        this.setState({
            description: l_Data,
            isLoading: true
        });
            this.setState({
                dateStack: l_Data;
            });

    });
```